# Google Analytics "Link Accounts" Link (With Adsense) Doesn't Work

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

[image: Link Google Analytics to Adsense account]

I am trying to link my Google Analytics profile with Adsense, but the "Link Account" which is supposed to allow me to do so, doesn't seem to work. It simply takes me to Adsense home page for logged in users, i.e. `https://www.google.com/adsense/v3/app`.

I see no options or instructions to integrate both accounts. Does anyone how to do this?

**PS:** both accounts are under the same Google account (i.e. same email address).

Comment: Does it happen to anyone else, or is it only me?

Comment: I've never been able to get my adsense account into my analytics account.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me.

1. Log in to your AdSense account. In the upper right side of your AdSense account, click on the cog or gear. A dropdown will appear with four selections. Click the top selection, which is *Settings*.
2. Once in Settings, the left side menu will change. In the left side menu, click on **Access and Authorization**. This will open a submenu. In that submenu, click on **Google Analytics Integration**.
3. Now you will see displayed all of the Properties you have in your Analytics account. In the upper right hand corner you will see the word **Link**. Click on **Link**.
4. This will open up your Google Analytics account in a new tab. It will take you directly to the Link Adsense page in your Google Analytics. Now when you click Link Accounts, it **won’t** take you to your AdSense Account, it will display a dialogue box asking which Google Analytics View to link with. Select your View and click save.

Your AdSense and Analytics accounts should now be linked.